# Openning 443 port with ufw

Tags: 18.04, ssl, ufw

Although `ufw status` shows that port 443 is allowed, the `netstat -tulpn` shows nothing.

```
root@machine:/etc/nginx/sites-available# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

root@machine:/etc/nginx/sites-available# netstat -tulpn | grep 443
root@machine:/etc/nginx/sites-available# netstat -tulpn | grep 80
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1518/python3.6 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29271/nginx: master
```

Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

`ufw` is allowing incoming connection to "443" but nothing is listening on that port, that's why `netstat` does not show anything.

try running:

```
$ sudo nc -lu 127.0.0.1 443
```

now `nc` is listening on "443", then run:

```
$ netstat -lan | grep 127.0.0.1:443
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:443           0.0.0.0:*
```